# Do Schengen entries and exits need to be recorded in a computer?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration

I was exiting Schengen border on a member airport, and at passport control, the officer that was far from the computer just stamped my passport without registration of my exit on the system.

I asked and he said that system registration is only necessary on entrance and not on exit.

Is this right? Then, how do they assure that I have not overstayed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> he said system registration is only necessary on entrance and not on Exit

If he actually said "system registration", he was wrong: there is no Schengen-wide "system registration" at all. When they scan your passport they just get a digital copy of your passport data along with possible alerts (such as arrest warrants) about the passenger, and they are supposed to do that on entry to the Schengen Area, and optionally on exit, though even on entry it's often not strictly followed, which really means nothing to you as a traveller.

Some countries have systems for their own use (which is not visible to the others), but it's still **only** the passport stamps that are the important thing. That's why you, as a non-EU/EFTA visitor, always have to make sure to get stamped when entering and exiting Schengen.

Sometimes, border agents (most commonly in France and Italy) will straight up lie and say it's "not needed" for "low-risk" passports (American, Australian etc.) because lifting their hand for a second seems to drain them of all life energy. They are breaking the law, however (specifically the Schengen Borders Code), by doing that, and you should never let them as **you** could get to pay for it.

Comment: There does appear to be newish (?) Schengen rules saying that passports have to be electronically scanned on _entry_ to the area. At least Copenhagen Airport is plastered with posters in which the police apologize for longer waits at passport control, blaming such new rules.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well yeah, but that doesn't mean the entries are recorded, just that the MRZ has to be systematically checked as a counter-fraud measure. And it's hardly taken seriously by all officers - since the rule was implemented I have, for example, entered Greece and Hungary by land, Germany, Italy and Sweden by air and the Euroairport (processed by a Swiss officer), and on many occasions they barely took my ID card in their hand.

Comment: x @Coke, the OP complained to the border guard that his passport was not scanned, and the border guard told him that passports are only scanned on entrance and not on exit. I see no reason to conclude from that, as you say that the border guard **was wrong** -- at most what is wrong is the OP's tacit assumption that the purpose of scanning the passport is to _register_ it in an underlying system (and his therefore-inaccurate paraphrase of what the border guard actually said to him).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I get you, changed the wording.

Comment: @HenningMakholm those new rules apply to EU passports only; they were already in place for others.  It's not only a scan of the MRZ but a police database lookup to see if the traveler is wanted for a serious crime.  The rules were changed after attacks in Paris by people with EU nationality who lived in Belgium.

Comment: @phoog Are those police databases Schengen-wide? I do know that when my ID is scanned in Switzerland (both at the internal and external border) my residence permit details pop up.

Comment: @Coke yes, and even wider, since the document is supposed to be checked against the Interpol database of lost and stolen documents, and the person may be checked against other Interpol databases.  I think it's in article 8 of the Schengen borders code.

Comment: Passport stamps are mandatory when entering or exiting Schengen? A quick scan of my own (EU) passport confirms my memory that I have never received a single stamp in any European airport, neither when entering nor when exiting. I’ve had my passport checked and scanned, but never stamped; I’ve entered/exited in France, Denmark, Norway, Sweden, Finland, Germany, the Netherlands, and Greece. Is this only a requirement for non-EU/non-Schengen passports?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well it's **not** mandatory for EU/EFTA passports, or Family member residence card holders, or, in certain member states, regular residence Permit holders. For non-EU/EFTA visitors, though, it is

Comment: I see. It might be a good idea to add that to the answer itself, to avoid alarming anyone who suddenly thinks they’ve been travelling illicitly all their lives. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For the bulk of us on here it's a basic fact, but sure!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also you cannot travel illegally as an EU/EFTA citizen, as you have an absolute right, by international law, to be in the EU and the Schengen Area. Hence no stamping.

Answer (score 5):

There's no Schengen-wide database of entries and exits.  They ensure that you haven't overstayed by looking at the stamps in your passport.  Yes, it's an imperfect system, but it is what it is.